# Installing Musescore 3.6.2 on Ubuntu 22.04LTS

Tags: software-installation, software-center

I installed Musescore 3.6.2 thru the Ubuntu Software installer, i.e. the software center, on my recently upgraded Ubuntu 22.04LTS. I set the "source" to "latest/stable," but after the install,in the app window's title bar, it  says  "unstable" and. . . it is! Is this an upstream versioning problem?

Comment: I'm just getting on Ubuntu. I've been on AV Linux using Musescore 3.6.2 just fine. Like phfactor said above, when I opened the Musescore through the Ubuntu software installer. It says "unstable". What do I do now? Ask the same question in the Musescore forum? Or do you have a solution now?
Thanks,
Sora

Answer (score 0):

The version 3.6.2 and the source "latest/stable" both suggest that you are using the snap (not the deb).

The snap is created and published by the Musescore upstream.

So, yes, you have apparently discovered a minor bug in the upstream packaging workflow.

And, yes, you should let them know about it: https://musescore.org/en/project/issues/musescore

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. I wasn't sure, since I got to the app install through Ubuntu's software tool, whether the problem was with Ubuntu or Musescore.